# css how to set the tr that has a speicifc id

Tags: css

**I know that this question is asked over internet for millions times. but because my english is bad i couldn't know the good words to search**

I have tr that has a specific ID like this:

```
<table class="tableClass">
<tr id="oneID">
</tr>
<tr id="secondID">
</tr>
</table>
```

I make my css like this:

```
.tableClass #oneID{}
```

and It works.

what I want is do something like this:

```
.tableClass tr[@id="oneID"]
```

Comment: What’s wrong with `.tableClass tr#oneID` …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
.tableClass tr#oneID
```

Answer (score 1):

without the `@` :

```
.tableClass tr[id="oneID"]
```

anyway a simple `#oneID` selector is enough. There's no need to create a too specific rule.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the selector

```
.tableClass tr#oneID {

}
```

but there is really no reason to, because element IDs must be unique, so the selector `tr#oneID` is overspecified. `#oneID` can match at most one element, so there is no point in writing a *more* specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use either

```
.tableClass #oneID
```

or

```
.tableClass [id="oneID"]
```

It's generally better practice to use the former, unless you need a partial match or to match a different attribute. The `tr` is unnecessary because there is no other `oneID`, which would be invalid. Less specific selectors are faster (albeit minutely), as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the row this way as well, using the nth-child selector.

```
.tableClass tr:nth-child(1){
}
```

This is assuming that the example provided will continue in the same way numerically.